# Predict reclaim size in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to know top ten table sizes and need to know how much older than data (in years) is available. The main query is once we decide to delete these many years data then how much space can release as free space inside the database files.

The tables can have child tables and indexes as well. If we delete the records in parent table then our script collectively should give how much space can reclaimed in the database files.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.+

Comment: Thanks for routing it to appropriate group.